# Automatticaly pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Every time a execute the 'git  push' command to push my local to the remote repo. It's automatically pushing to Heroku. I'd like to do the regular 'git push heroku' command. Would it be possible to change it?

Comment: What `git remote -v` returns?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `git push origin <branch>` and it pushes to heroku, this simply means your origin is pointed to heroku, you can confirm this by checking yur remotes `git remote -v`.

You can however change this by removing or renaming your remotes then adding them again with `git remote add heroku <link to the repo>`